# javascript : parsing multi-level json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have a asp.net web service that returns a multi-level array.

the json string is parse using the json2.js lib :

```
var donnee = JSON.parse(msg.d);
```

the 1st level parsing is ok but the 2nd level array (data) remains as an array of objects

> ? donnee[0]

```
{...}
color: "#0000CD"
data: [[object Object],[object Object]]
label: "formol"
type: "traitement"
```

> ? donnee[0].data

```
[[object Object],[object Object]]
[0]: {...}
[1]: {...}
```

> ? donnee[0].data[0]

```
{...}
_l: ""
_x: 7
_y: 25
```

whereas I need an array of data e.g.

> ? donnee[0]

```
{...}
label: "traitement formol 2"
type: "traitement"
color: "#0000CD"
data: [7,25,,7,40,formol]
```

> ? donnee[0].data

```
[7,25,,7,40,formol]
[0]: [7,25,]
[1]: [7,40,formol]
```

> ? donnee[0].data[0]

```
[7,25,]
[0]: 7
[1]: 25
[2]: ""
```

what is the best way to decode/parse all the levels of the json string at once ?

best regards

Comment: It already is "parsed" completely. That's what a JSON parser does, unless the object contains strings that are themselves JSON-serialized objects (which is not the case here, apparently; if it were, you'd see strings, not objects or arrays of objects).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply
Do you mean that I need first to serialize the 2nd level as a string then use this string as a property of the 1st level and then serialize the whole data?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. The job of "parsing" the initial JSON string is done **completely** by that single call to "JSON.parse()".  The task you have to undertake is to *traverse* the resulting data structure. Where is this JSON coming from? If you don't know what the structure of the data is, how are you going to be able to use it?

Comment: No problem, it's my web service. Here is the detail :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"_infoType":"traitement1","color":"#0000CD","data":[{"_l":"","_x":7,"_y":25},{"_l":"format","_x":7,"_y":40}],"label":"formol","type":"traitement"}]</string>

Answer (score 0):

I have so far not found a simple solution to decode the json string in pure array. For now I parse the string and replace directly the object by an array .

```
var donnee = JSON.parse(msg.d);

                for (var i in donnee) {

                    if (donnee.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

                        datas[i] = donnee[i];

                        for (var j in donnee[i]) {

                            if (donnee[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {

                                var lev2 = donnee[i][j];

                                if (typeof lev2 == "object") {
                                    for (var k in donnee[i][j]) {
                                        var lev3 = donnee[i][j][k];
                                        datas[i].data[k] = new Array(lev3.x, lev3.y, lev3.l);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```